# How to get input text value from input tag?

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, popup

I have created newsletterpopup with two fields, 'email address' and 'subscriber's name'. And I have made input tag for this both field. So now I want to get the subscriber's name in a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: please mention where you need this values

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get value in controller , You can use -

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$var = $data['input_field_name'];
```

Or if you want to get value in your template file than you can get it using following javascript code-

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById('input_field_id').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to get `input values` in controller: You can use below code in your controller(which point your POST action):

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
zend_debug::dump($data);
```